# How to align comma values vertically within a Cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am preparing one excel form to be fill up by the user. Within this form at one step user select the multiple values from UserForm listbox and upon submission those values gets stored in excel cell which is merged.
but the problem is when user submit from listbox it looks like this (Just an e.g.)  **Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday** but how I want them to display is the same way it was reflecting in Listbox vertically. i.e. Monday then on next line Tuesday etc. is there any way to display this data in Vertical format?
Below is the code which transfer the multiple values select by user in the Cell.

```
myvar2 = ""

For x = 0 To Me.LBXC.ListCount - 1
    If Me.LBXC.Selected(x) Then
        If myvar2 = "" Then
            myvar2 = Me.LBXC.List(x, 0)
        Else
            myvar2 = myvar2 & "," & Me.LBXC.List(x, 0)
        End If
    End If
Next x

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ASC").Range("E20") = myvar2
```

Comment: Replace the "," by vbLf

Comment: Omg the solution was in the code itself. Thank you so much Vincent G. God bless you.